# Proving that $M :=\{A\subseteq\mathbb N: A\text{ or }A^{\complement}\text{ is finite}\}$ is infinitely and countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am having some problems proving the above. Basically I need to find a surjective function $f: \Bbb N \rightarrow M $  .

I also figured out that $ M \subset\wp(\Bbb N)$ which is uncountable. Alternatively I could show $$M = \bigcup_{j =1}^n \{A_j ⊆ \Bbb N: A_j\text{ or } A_j^{\complement}\text{ is finite }\} $$

Anyway, I have no idea how to do it. So any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much. Best regards.

Comment: @drhab It means the cardinality is finite. Edited it in the text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M_{Fin}:=\{A\in\wp(\mathbb N)\mid A\text{ is finite}\}$ and $M_{Cof}:=\{A\in\wp(\mathbb N)\mid A^{\complement}\text{ is finite}\}$. Then $M_{Fin}$ and $M_{Cof}$ have the same cardinality and $M=M_{Fin}\cup M_{Cof}$.

So for proving that $M$ is countable it is enough to prove that $M_{Fin}$ is countable.

We can write $M_{Fin}=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} M_n$ where $M_n$ denotes the collection of all subsets $\mathbb N$ that have cardinality $n$.

This shows that it is enough to prove that for each $n$ the set $M_n$ is countable, since a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Can you do that yourself?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I understand the second part but I am not quite sure about the first part. What does $A^C$ mean. And why is the cardinality of Mfin and Mcof the same?

Comment: $A^{\complement}$ stands for $\mathbb N\setminus A$. It is the so-called complement of $A$. There is a function $f:M_{Fin}\to M_{Cof}$ prescribed by $A\mapsto A^{\complement}$. Also there is a function $g:M_{Cof}\to M_{Fin}$ again prescribed by $A\mapsto A^{\complement}$. These functions are inverses of each other hence are bijective.

Comment: That makes perfectly sence. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome.